# object oriented programming

Tags: oop

Is the nesting of functions possible in the object oriented languages like C#, Java, C++ etc . If so, can anyone give an example?

Comment: What are you trying to solve? Or is it just curiosity?

Comment: No, because (1) we aren't slaves, (2) you have made no effort at all, (3) you specified 3 languages plus "etc", (4) I don't see any capital letters, (5) this is a lazy question that Google solves, not StackOverflow.

Comment: A downvote from me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having nested function is irrelevant to being object-oriented.

---

- C# doesn't have nested functions, but you can use lambdas (See [Why doesn't C# have lexically nested functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576374/why-doesnt-c-have-lexically-nested-functions)). So are all other programming languages that support anonymous functions (including C++0x).
- You may create a local class, and overload the call operator to simulate a nested function (See [is it possible in C or C++ to create a function inside another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256647/is-it-possible-in-c-or-c-to-create-a-function-inside-another)).
- Meanwhile, many non-object-oriented languages like (the original) Pascal support nested functions natively, and GCC support it in C as an extension.

Answer (score 0):

[Implementing Nested Functions in C#](http://www.codeguru.com/columns/vb/article.php/c12749).

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have pointed out, because you can create anonymous functions in most languages these days, you can assign such a function object to a variable, and that effectively results in a local function (although recursion may be tricky).

In C++ prior to C++1x anonymous functions (known as lambdas) are not yet available. However, you can still declare a function inside a function, because you can declare a class or struct inside a function. If you make that class implement `operator()`, then instantiate the class and store it in a named variable, you will have effectively achieved the same as a lamda in C++1x.

The problem is that it will (a) be much more verbose and (b) it won't be permissible as an argument to a template.

Answer (score 0):

Java is another one OO language.
It does not support nested methods, but it does support nested class (it could help in workaround):
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/whentouse.html